# Static groovy methods with same name, but different parameter types

Tags: methods, groovy, static

I have the following example in a Groovy class :

static A extract(List of A ) {}

static B extract(List of B ) {}

The weird behavior is that only the first method is recognized from outside, but the second isn't, I was writing unit tests for this class when I came across this issue.

Does anyone know why it behaves this way? The class is only annotated with @Component Spring annotation.

Comment: Can you share real code?

Comment: Unfortunately, not the exact  classes, but the situation in code is as simple as I described. the only thing that differs between the two methods is the return type and list of objects received as parameter. First method received a list of A objects and returns a certain A object. Same for the second method.